# The indicator-netspeed is not displayed

Tags: indicator, git

I have installed Ubuntu 14.04 LTS and I want to install this indicator https://github.com/mgedmin/indicator-netspeed

So, I pasted this into my Terminal

```
sudo apt-get install build-essential libgtop2-dev libgtk-3-dev libappindicator3-dev git-core
git clone git://github.com/mgedmin/indicator-netspeed.git
cd indicator-netspeed
make
sudo make install
indicator-netspeed &
```

It's was installed sucessfull but nothing is displayed. What I did wrong? How can I remove it and install again?Help me please.

Answer (score 0):

it should work

1. just open the ubuntu software Center, type the application name (if the app have installed succesfully it should displayed) and left click the app.. then click the "remove" button... done.
2. from terminal (ctrl+alt+T) type :

sudo apt-get remove

hit enter and type your password, if it ask "Do you want to continue [Y/n]? " type "Y"
wait till finished..

for the indicator netspeed u can use this http://www.webupd8.org/2014/04/indicator-netspeed-displays-network.html

Hope its works and sorry for my bad english... :-)